# Scraper is fetching data based on lines, how can I change this?

Tags: php

When someone submits a url, it grabs certain data from the site and displays it on a table on my site. Now it worked a few times, but now on the table it is displaying `</a> <tr > </td>`

I was told the problem with the current scraper is it fetches data based on lines. How can I make it based on regular expressions?

Thanks.

```
$html = file($link);

    // iterate through html
    foreach ($html as $i => $line)
    {
        // set title
        if($i == 640) $title = htmlentities($line);

        // set requester
        if($i==669) $requester = htmlentities($line);

        if($i==678)
        {
            // modify the line and save as reward
            $line_modified = str_replace($findme2, '', $line);
            $line_modified = str_replace($findme3, '', $line_modified);
            $reward = htmlentities($line_modified);
        }

        // set qualifications
        if($i==711) $q = htmlentities($line);
    }
```

Comment: First time I've heard of using line numbers to scrape things... Parse the HTML.

Comment: We'll need to see what is on those lines to be able to give you a Regex for it.